# Highlighting multiple cells in a row based on other values in the row in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am trying to highlight cells in my pandas dataframe based on two conditions:

- If A cell - B cell > 10 highlight B cell in green else if ((B cell - A cell)/B cell * 100) > 20 highlight B cell in red
- If A cell - C cell > 10 highlight C cell in green else if ((C cell - A cell)/C cell * 100) > 20 highlight C cellin red

```
i  A  B  C   D
0  4  2  3  Jim
1  3  3  2  Bob
2  3  2  4  Joe
```

I tried some variations of apply() and applymap() with subset but I wasn't able to do what i wanted.

Comment: @druidmaceik, when you say highlight, you mean in excel or in jupyter notebook (e.g. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html)

Comment: I mean in excel but i think the Styler.apply() works on both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at : https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

You'll basically end up with something like:

```
    excel_file = StringIO.StringIO()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file,
                            engine='xlsxwriter')
    some_data_frame.to_excel(writer,
                             sheet_name='some_sheet_name',
                             engine='xlsxwriter',
                             encoding='utf-8')
    worksheet = writer.sheets['some_sheet_name']
    worksheet.conditional_format('B',
                                 {'type': 'cell',
                                  'criteria': '>=',
                                  'value': 5,
                                  'format': hot
                                  })
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

In your case you would set the value equal to your calculation.

Comment: sorry made an edit, pivot was just a dataframe from my code base. you just use the `.to_excel()` function which can be called from any pandas DataFrame

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out based on your answer.